# How do I tell the system to treat one of the ruby-build rubies as the system ruby?

Tags: ruby

I don't have any ruby installed on my linux mint by apt-get. Instead, I installed ruby using [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build#installing-as-a-standalone-program-advanced). I now have ruby installation in

```
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/
```

How do I make this ruby installation the 'system' ruby just like apt-get sets ruby executable during apt-get install ruby1.9.1 for example.

I want to register this version as system ruby and when I use rubies switching with chruby (or rvm or rbenv) I want that to be seen as system ruby?

Do I simply use update-alternatives? Do I reinstall ruby from source with make? Any other suggestions please.

Comment: This is not a direct answer (hence, a comment) but have you considered using [rbenv global](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#rbenv-global)?

Comment: I am using chruby for switching. I think the question is valid no matter if you use rvm, chruby or rbenv. I just want to set one o the rubies to be the default system ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had previously installed ruby with

```
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

then the apt process sets up alternatives so I have an entry for ruby group

```
/usr/bin/ruby -> /etc/alternatives/ruby
```

Now I can simply add my own ruby installation to the ruby group

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ruby ruby /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby 1
```

and either set or config alternative to point to the ruby I want

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set ruby /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby
# or sudo update-alternatives --config ruby
# and select the entry I want
```

The above I can do only after I have original alternatives set by apt-get during ruby install.

However If I DO NOT have ruby installed with apt-get then I can use the same mechanism even if I don't have /etc/alternatives/ruby in place yet.

I just do the following

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/ruby ruby /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby 1
```

additionally I may want to add gem as well.

What I am not sure about is how does that affect the gems installed

Answer (score 1):

You can add the path to your custom ruby build in the $PATH environment variable.

```
export PATH="/my-build-path/bin:$PATH"
```

(or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a system Ruby, use ruby-build to install the Ruby into /usr/local:

```
$ ruby-build 2.0.0-p0 /usr/local/
```

Comment: ha! but I already have it installed in /opt/rubies/ and since I am lazy I don't want to reinstall. There has to be a way... 

one possible way is to use update-alternatives /usr/bin/ruby ruby /opt/rubies.... however I don't have an entry in ruby group in alternatives system... so I am curious how I can accomplish this.